# Should I return 'object-argument' from a method that modified that 'object-argument' in Java?

Tags: java, oop

Which style is preferred for the following examples of code?

## 1

```
class Player
{
    Player() { this.id = UID.generate(); }
}

void fillPlayerData(Player player, PlayerRequest playerRequest)
{
    player.name = playerRequest.name;
    ...    
}
```

or

```
Player fillPlayerData(Player player, PlayerRequest playerRequest)
{
    player.name = playerRequest.name;
    ...
    return player;    
}
```

## 2

```
void setErrors(Object object, List<Error> errors)
{
    object.status = Status.ERROR;
    ...
    object.addAll(errors);
}
```

or

```
Object setErrors(Object object, List<Error> errors)
{
    object.status = Status.ERROR;
    ...
    object.addAll(errors);
    return object;
}
```

**Update**:
Which one is better to use in RxJava:

## 3

```
Single<Object> returnObject(Object object)
{
    return loadSingle
       .doOnSuccess(objectResponse -> fillData(object, objectResponse))
       .doOnError(e -> addErrors(object, e))
       .toCompletable()
       .andThen(Single.just(object));
}
```

## 4

```
Single<Object> returnObject(Object object)
{
    return loadSingle
       .map(objectResponse -> fillData(object, objectResponse))
       .onErrorReturn(e -> addErrors(object, e));
}
```

Comment: The invoker already has the reference of a mutable object and hence returning the reference to same object to the invoker is useless. You should do that in case of primitive or non mutable objects

Comment: @nits.kk it's not useless for method chaining, although `fillPlayerData` should probably be a method inside `Player` instead of taking one as a parameter.

Comment: @Kayaman actually I use RxJava so I'm thinking about should I switch from `.map` to `.doOnNext` operator.

Comment: Then why did you put useless pseudocode in your question that's not related to RxJava?

Comment: @Kayaman I saw this problem in my non-rx code, too.

Comment: @Kayaman thanks for reminding me of Chaining which is one case where returning the same object makes it easier for the invoker. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of methods you have are basically modifying the parameters. There are three cases possible

[Case 1] Passed parameters are (is) primitive

```
public void invoker(){
    int x = 20;
    int increment = 30;
    x = getIncrementedValue(x,increment);
}
public int getIncrementedValue(int x, int inc){
     return x+inc;
}
```

[Case 2] Passed parameters are (is) non mutable

```
public void invoker(){
    String x = "kk";
    String y = nits;
    x = getAppendedString(x,y);

}
public String getAppendedString(String a, String b){
     a = a.append(b); // as Strings are non mutable hence this is not changed on the original passed object. The assignment of a also does not make any difference as it's local variable.
  return a
}
```

[Case 3] Passed parameters are (is) mutable object reference.

```
 public void invoker(){
    Student s = new Student();       
    promoteStudent(s);
 }
public void promoteStudent(Student s){
     s.standard++;
     // No need to return the object reference as same object has been modified and reference of the same is present with the invoker.
}

public class Student{
    int standard = 1;
}
```

**Edit**
Another use case as mentioned in the comments. The returning of the same object is useful in case of chaining.

```
 public class Student{
       String name;
       int roll;
       int standard;
       public Student setName(String n){ this.name =n; return this;}
       public Student setRoll(int n){ this.roll =n; return this;}
       public Student setStandard(int n){ this.standard =n; return this}
      public int getFees(){
           return standard*2;
      }
}
...
public void someMethod(Student s){

 Int fees = s.setName("KK").setRoll(30).setStandard(10).getFees();
  // Other lines of code ..
 }
```